# dual space of space of space of bounded continuous maps

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces

$T: C_b(X, \mathbb R)\to C_b(X,\mathbb R)$ a linear map where $X$ is complete, separable, locally compact metric space. $C_b(X,\mathbb R)$ is vector space of all bounded continuous functions. Can I say that $T^*: M_1(X)\to M_1(X)$ where $M(X)$ is space of all probability measures on $X$? Thanks!

Comment: $T^{*}$ is define don the dual of $C_b(X,\mathbb R)$ so unless you have   Riesz Theorem for non-locally compact spaces yo ucannot consider it as a map on $M(X)$.

Comment: Probability measures don't even form a vector space.

Comment: "then is the answer wrong here?" No. That other question is about $C([0,1])$. Since $[0,1]$ is compact, $C_b([0,1])=C([0,1])$ and the dual is the space of complex measures.

Comment: I have no idea what your question  is...

Comment: It's certainly a closely related question. The "topological dual" of a topological vector space is the space of _continuous_ linear functionals - usually just called the dual..

Comment: what does the accepted answer says , could you please explain me a bit? At least the first paragraph/first line.

Comment: It says "Take the algebra $\mathcal A$ generated by the closed sets in $\mathbb R$.  The space of finitely-additive signed measures on $\mathcal A$, with variation norm, is the dual of $C_b(\mathbb R)$." I have no way of knowing what you want me to explain unless you ask a mmore specific question. Really - do you want me to start by explaining what $\Bbb R$ is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Even for locally compact $X$, the dual  of $C_b(X)$ is larger than the space of (regular Borel) measures.

Say $X=\Bbb N$, so $C_b(X)=\ell_\infty$. Let $\Lambda\in\ell_\infty^*$ be a Banach limit, which is to say that $\Lambda x=\lim_{j\to\infty}x_j$ for all $x\in\ell_\infty$ such that the limit exists. Then $\Lambda$ is not given by a measure on $X$.

**Note** $\Bbb N$ is certainly locally compact and separable; it's also complete in the standard metric $|n-m|$.

**In fact** one can give an analogous example if $X$ is any non-compact locally compact Hausdorff space. A bit of Banach algebra stuff shows that $C_b(X)$ is isometrically isomorphic to $C(K)$, where $K$ is a certain compact Hausdorff space containing $X$ as a dense subset. Any measure on $K$ which is not supported on $X$ gives an  example of a bounded linear functional on $C_b(X)$ which does not arise from a measure on $X$.

Comment: Someone explain what the problem is...

Comment: +1 from me. I misread $C_b$ as $C_c$ and claimed that the result was true for locally compact case. I have deleted my comment.

Comment: "what does this question and answer says then?" It says what it says - what's the question?